# Complete bipartite planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

For which $n,m$ is $K_{n,m}$ planar? Justify an answer.

I made conclusion that for $K_{n,m}$, where $2 \leq n,m $ then $K_{n,m}$ is not planar not depenting whether $n$ or $m$ is odd or even. Is it true? I want to use Theorem which states that is a triangle- free graph $e(G) \leq 2 n(G)-4$. Since bipartite graphs are triangle free this should hold however $mn \leq 2(m+n) - 4$ does not hold for $n=4$,$m=5$ for example and for numbers bigger. But is this really enough for the proof?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $K_{3,3}$ is non-planar. So when we have $m \ge 3$ and $n \ge 3$, the graph will have $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraph, so by **Kuratowski's Theorem** it is non-planar. For the rest, you only should look $K_{2,m}$ for all $m$, which is obviously planar (you can draw it and see). So in general, it is planar for $n \le 2$ and when this condition is satisfied, it is independent from $m$.

Comment: Oh I see.. thank you!

Comment: By the way, I said obvious but if you want me to explain it, I will try to explain it by using the length of cycles. Would you like me to explain? But your argument $mn \leq 2(m+n) - 4$ is correct so you can find it out yourself by just putting $n = 2$.

Comment: No thank you, I think it would be enough to explain how graphs of the form $K_{2,m}$ are drawn without an intersection to justify an answer right?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I used. Moreover, if we can draw it, in my opinion, it is the best way of showing planarity :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)